# Python PDF plumber multiple data reading

Tags: python, pandas, pdf

i am using PDF Plumber in a process to extract data from PDF invoices. A problem occured, when i loaded multiple PDFs. All the files upload to the code, but when i use the exctractor of the text ( PDF Plumber), it gives me data only from the last pdf that was downloaded. The PDFs are always the same, so the startPhrase and the endPhrase are the same. Just the numbers change. Has anyone had the same problem ? Here is the part of the code.

- I download the files from email
- Then have the text extractor

  ```
  def extractWordsFromPdfContentsBetweenPhrases(page, startPhrase, endPhrase):
      text = page.extract_text()
      contents = (text[text.find(start)+len(start):text.rfind(end)])
      splitter = string.strip().split()
      return splitter
  ```

Then i use the extractor in a function, puts specific data into a DataFrame.

```
def readDataFromSavedMails():
    for filename in os.listdir(workingFolder):
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            ap = (workingFolder + filename)
            with pdfplumber.open(ap) as pdf:
                splitterFirstPage = extractWordsFromPdfContentsBetweenPhrases(pdf.pages[1],'Údaje o měřicím zařízení','Zúčtované částky celkem')
                splitterSecondPage = extractWordsFromPdfContentsBetweenPhrases(pdf.pages[1],'VYÚČTOVÁNÍ SPOTŘEBY ELEKTŘINY KE DNI','Údaje o měřicím zařízení')  
                splitterThirdPage = extractWordsFromPdfContentsBetweenPhrases(pdf.pages[0],'Nedoplatek ve výši','prosíme uhraďte do data splatnosti')   
                dateOD = splitterFirstPage[10]
                dateDO = splitterFirstPage[11]
                spotreba = splitterFirstPage[33]
                cena = splitterThirdPage[0]
                ean = splitterSecondPage[7]
    return pd.DataFrame({'EAN':[ean],'DatumOD': [dateOD], 'DatumDo': [dateDO], 'Spotřeba v kWh':[spotreba],'Cena v CZK':[cena]})
```

The data in the dataframe is only from the last pdf and not all of the downloaded ones.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

**IICU**

```
`import glob
 from tqdm.auto import tqdm

 for current_pdf_file in tqdm(glob.glob("Path/*.pdf")):
    with pdfplumber.open(current_pdf_file) as my_pdf:

         # do other things here?`
```

Comment: would be great if You added some explanation about Your code since to some it may not be understandable, like explain what each step does and stuff, unless it is super simple but this doesn't seem like so, for example explain what `glob` does